# c# merge images sent over socket

Tags: c#, sockets, image-processing

im trying to send screenshots over socket so i use unsafe pointers to send only the differences:

```
    private unsafe Bitmap GetDiffBitmap(Bitmap bmp, Bitmap bmp2)
    {


        bmpRes = new Bitmap(1920, 1080,bmp.PixelFormat);

        bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
        bmDataRes = bmpRes.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpRes.Width, bmpRes.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;
        IntPtr scan0Res = bmDataRes.Scan0;


        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        int stride2 = bmData2.Stride;
        int strideRes = bmDataRes.Stride;

        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;

        //for(int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, nHeight, y =>
        {
            //define the pointers inside the first loop for parallelizing
            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
            p += y * stride;
            byte* p2 = (byte*)scan02.ToPointer();
            p2 += y * stride2;
            byte* pRes = (byte*)scan0Res.ToPointer();
            pRes += y * strideRes;

            for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
            {
                //always get the complete pixel when differences are found
                if (p[0] != p2[0] || p[1] != p2[1] || p[2] != p2[2])
                {
                    pRes[0] = p2[0];
                    pRes[1] = p2[1];
                    pRes[2] = p2[2];

                    //alpha (opacity)
                    pRes[3] = p2[3];
                }

                p += 4;
                p2 += 4;
                pRes += 4;
            }

        });



        bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);
        bmp2.UnlockBits(bmData2);
        bmpRes.UnlockBits(bmDataRes);

        return bmpRes;
    }
```

this is the call on the client:

```
   private void startSend()
    {

        Bitmap curr;

        Bitmap pre = screenshot();

        byte []bmpBytes = imageToByteArray(pre);

        SendVarData(handler, bmpBytes);// this is the first send of the whole screen

        while (true)
        {

            curr = screenshot();
            Bitmap diff = GetDiffBitmap(pre, curr);//generate differences.
            bmpBytes = imageToByteArray(diff);
            SendVarData(handler, bmpBytes);//sending the diff image.
            pre = curr; 


        }
    }
```

`SendVarData` is a method which send the bytes array over the socket **it is not the problem here-leave it.**

this is how i get the data in the server side:

```
  public void startListening()
    {

        Bitmap merge = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(merge);
         Bitmap  prev =  byteArrayToImage(ReceiveVarData(client.Client)) as  Bitmap;//getting the first full size image.

        theImage.Image = prev;//assisning it to picturebox.


        while (true)
        {
            byte[]data = ReceiveVarData(client.Client);

           Bitmap  curr = byteArrayToImage(data) as Bitmap;//here is the diffrent image

           //merge and apply differences
                g.DrawImage(prev, 0, 0,1920, 1080);
                g.DrawImage(curr, 0, 0, 1920,1080);

            theImage.Image = merge;

            count++;

            prev = merge;
        }  

    }
```

my problem is that eventhough i merge the two images with the Graphics.Draw it still(after the first dataReceive) looks like not full... this is actually what i see on the server..[image]

i dont know what's wrong here... can anyone light my eyes? :D
@DmitriTrofimov

```
    if (p[0] != p2[0] || p[1] != p2[1] || p[2] != p2[2])
                {
                    pRes[0] = p2[0];
                    pRes[1] = p2[1];
                    pRes[2] = p2[2];

                    //alpha (opacity)
                    pRes[3] = p2[3];
                }
                else
                    pRes[0] = 0;
```

Comment: Is `SendVarData` compressing the data before/while sending?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen compressing by using GzipStream or any other compression methods? no.

Comment: Then why not just send the entire image, why deal with working out the changes at all?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen even after compression-its very big data -100kb~200kb and also compression is pretty slow even lz4

Comment: But if you're not compressing it, aren't you still sending the whole image, just large portions of it will be transparent/black? I mean, bytes are bytes, regardless of their value. What exactly did you save by creating a new bitmap containing only the differences?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  tnx but i think im done with this. now i got a new problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361485/c-sharp-mering-images-algorithm i would realy appericiate if you could help there

Comment: I think that if the answer here worked you wouldn't need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you get when you keep pixel opacity. You should set Alpha to zero on the pixels that are not different and make sure you are working with 32-bit images (refer to `PixelFormat` parameter of `Bitmap` constructor).

P.S. Make sure you compress the diff bitmap otherwise it's no use.

Comment: thank you very much did u mean like this? @DmitriTrofimov                                                 `    if (p[0] != p2[0] || p[1] != p2[1] || p[2] != p2[2])
                    {
                        pRes[0] = p2[0];
                        pRes[1] = p2[1];
                        pRes[2] = p2[2];

                        //alpha (opacity)
                        pRes[3] = p2[3];
                    }
                    else
                        pRes[0] = 0;`

Comment: oh it seems too messy here i'll write it in the question itself below. tell me if i wrote if this what you meant to.@DmitriTrofimov

Comment: I think it should be `pRes[3] = 0;` since just two lines above you have a comment `// alpha`, so I assume the index should be `3`.